# Get type of Window in readable format

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I just started learning C# and WPF. Is there a way to get the type of window? For example, I'm using this to get the text on the Window:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
```

This returns: "Ask a Question - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome"

I want to only obtain "Google Chrome". I tried

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll")]
public static extern int GetClassName (IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);
```

This returns "Chrome_WidgetWin_1". Is there a better approach that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a "type" like you describe assigned to the window. The closest thing would be the class name which you already retrieved.

You can parse the title text though to just extract the last value if all windows follow the  same title text pattern of "some text" - "whatever" - "Google Chrome". The number of dashes or whatever doesn't matter as long as there is a dash before "Google Chrome" you can extract it as such

```
string windowTypeName = string.Split('-').LastOrDefault();
```

This will return "Google Chrome" or null if there is no title text or dash in the title text.

**Edit**

You could also get the process name associated with the window and if it's chrome.exe then you can just assume the window type is "Google Chrome"

Comment: Yea, I suppose that's the best way